# zip code is still required even disabling AVS in authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have successfully created the customer profile along with a payment profile. but when i create more payment profile to the same profile ID . It gives me the error of

> Create Customer Payment Profile: ERROR Invalid response Response : E00027 There is one or more missing or invalid required fields.

In the documentation it was written that zip code is required in case of the AVS enabled so i disabled it but still it is showing error unless i add the zip code field.

Any help in this regard.?

Comment: It also says, "Required when using GPN Canada or Worldpay Streamline Processing Platform." Are you using either one of those platforms?

Comment: no i am not using either of these and using only the visa card or the master card right now. you can also see the difference by going to the api test code and delete the zip code in both (create customer profile and create customer payment profile).  Create customer profile will work whether create customer payment profile will not.

Comment: I won't be able to try to duplicate this until I get home in a few hours. I will report back my findings here when I do.

Comment: Looks like that field is required. You might want to reach out to Authorize.Net for further support or to have them update their documentation.

Comment: @JohnConde not only this but i think this is a notable bug that while creating a profile it did not demands the zip code in payment profile. but if we are updating the profile only it demands the zip code to be included.